# ¿Por que no me recoce el salto de linea en una funcion PHP?

Tags: php, html5, funciones

requiero de su ayuda, estoy manejando un formulario HTML basico con una funcion PHP que trae datos de la base de datos, los datos ya los trae pero los trae en una sola columna, determine el salto de linea con el 
, pero sigue sin realizar el salto de linea.
que me recomiendan para solucionar este detalle.
este es el codigo de la función PHP que manejo;

```
    <?PHP
                        include "Conexion.php";
                        $conn1 = new ConexionBD1();
                        try 
                        {
                            $qry="Exec POST_RemisionesSelect";
                            $stmt = $conn1->conn->prepare($qry);
                            $stmt->execute();

                            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                            /* fila por fila */
                            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
                            {
                                echo
                                "<td>" . $row['fec'] . "</td>" . 
                                "<td>" . $row['numRem'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['cli']  . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['carb'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['tom'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['can'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['ltr'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['pre'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['porDes'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['preFin'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['Desu'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['pro'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['cob'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['frmPag'] . "</td>" .
                                "<td>" . $row['estatus'] . "<br />";
                            }

                        }
                        catch(PDOException $e) {
                            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu primer error es introducir el salto de línea HTML de esta forma:

```
...
"<td>" . $row['frmPag'] . "</td>" .
"<td>" . $row['estatus'] . "<br />";
```

No estás cerrando el elemento `td`, para el caso el código debería ser:

```
...
"<td>" . $row['frmPag'] . "</td>" .
"<td>" . $row['estatus'] . "</td><br />";
```

pero esto tampoco es *correcto*. Creo que tu intención es mostrar los datos en una tabla, por eso el uso de `td`, estas creando celdas. Ahora bien deberías introducirlas en filas, crearías una fila por cada registro de datos que vas a mostrar, así en tu HTML al final tendrías:

```
<tr>
   <td>Dato 1</td>
   <td>Dato 2</td>
   <td>Dato 3</td>
   ...
</tr>
```

Cómo estas imprimiendo directamente podrías hacer algo así:

```
/* fila por fila */
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
{
    echo "<tr>" .
    "<td>" . $row['fec'] . "</td>" . 
    "<td>" . $row['numRem'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['cli']  . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['carb'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['tom'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['can'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['ltr'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['pre'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['porDes'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['preFin'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['Desu'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['pro'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['cob'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['frmPag'] . "</td>" .
    "<td>" . $row['estatus'] . "<br />" .
    "</tr>";
}
```

Y todo esto dentro de una tabla, que imprimirías fuera del bucle.

Consulta como crear tablas HTML, por ejemplo [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

Comment: ah, muchas gracias, ya lo intente asi como me comento y es correcto,
ya quedo el formulario con los saltos de linea.
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0fxR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0fxR.png)